# Does winning the lottery increase odds of committing suicide?

Tags: suicide, finance

I've heard on a few occasions claims that one should not play the lottery because it increases the odds of committing suicide later.  Here are a few articles I found that at least reference the idea:

http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2010/02/19/lotto-death-curse.html

http://time.com/4176128/powerball-jackpot-lottery-winners/

**What affect does winning the lottery have on the odds that an individual will choose to commit, or attempting, suicide?**

For this question lets define 'winning' the lottery as winning a minimum of $10,000 dollars from a single ticket.  I'm also happy to accept studies that look only at the affect of larger lottery winnings then the 10,000 minimum I set.

I'm asking specifically rather winning the lottery *increases* an individual's risk of suicide, not if lottery winners have a higher chance of suicide then non-winners.  Since a number of factors which increase odds of an individual playing the lottery are also correlated with chance of committing suicide, most obviously socioeconomic level, I'd prefer to look at studies that attempted to correct for this effect if possible.

Comment: There's an additional confounding factor, that will influence both (I think) the risks you inquire about and the collection of data: not all jurisdictions require you to make your identity public in order to claim the prize.